# How to create a connection string uning Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

How to create a connection string using Visual Studio 2010?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the connection to Server Explorer, then right click on the connection and select properties. The Properties window shows the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly VS, but works anywhere:

- In the notepad create empty file blabla.udl
- Doubleclick in explorer on it
- Edit all connections parameter & driver in system dialog
- Apply changes and reopen file in notepad

It will contain valid connection string